# Save into variable parameter generated when page redirects on Rails server

Tags: ruby-on-rails, get

I have a Echosign pdf that is esigned by user and once this happens, the user is redirected to a url that has ?documentKey=3r3t33hhjijij appended to it. I do not generate the key and it is only generated once the pdf is signed. This key is not the same for each pdf signed.

I can watch in my console:

```
Started GET "/webpage?documentKey=3r3t33hhjijij" for ip address ....
Processing by Controller#index as HTML
  Parameters: {'documentKey"=>3r3t33hhjijij"}...
```

I have no clue how to log this/get this into variable since it happens after pdf is signed, not after I call an Echosign API method.

Thanks for any help in advance.

I am using Rails 3.2.8

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the `index` action of your controller you can access any parameter passed in as a query string using `params[:key]`, e.g. `params[:documentKey]`.

So the following would output to the console:

```
@docKey = params[:documentKey]
logger.info "Key: #{@docKey}"
```

**Edit**

In case there is a problem with routing, define the following (let's call your controller `mypdf` and the action `echosign`). Add the following line to your `config/routes.rb`.

```
match 'mypdf/echosign' => 'mypdf#echosign', :as => 'echosign'
```

Let's assume the users are directed to `/echosign?documentKey=ksdjfshdfjh` on your site.

So in your controller, if the following is defined:

```
class MypdfController < ApplicationController
  def echosign
     logger.info "Reached echosign"
     logger.info "Document key is #{params[:documentKey]}"
     redirect_to(root_url)
  end
end
```

then when users are directed to the page after signing their PDF, you should see:

```
Started GET "/echosign?documentKey=ksdjfshdfjh" for 127.0.0.1 at 2013-02-14 23:27:49 -0700
  Processing by MypdfController#echosign as HTML
  Parameters: {"documentKey"=>"ksdjfshdfjh"}
Reached echosign
Document key is ksdjfshdfjh
```

Comment: This isn't working, I don't understand why it's not. I've tried it in multiple controllers and it says it's nil. Does this params[:documentKey] get cleared at some point? Thanks for the help.

Comment: undefined method `[]' for nil:NilClass

Comment: `params` would not be cleared by Rails. It looks like documentKey *is not* being passed as a parameter to Rails. In the controller, if you insert the statement `logger.info "#{params.inspect}"`, what do you then see in the console?

Comment: Sorry - it looks like it is not being passed to Rails as a parameter in the URL. I'm not clear on the steps the user is taking, what is calling echosign and how the documentKey is being returned.

Comment: I am using the createUrlWidget api method to generate a pdf for e-signing. Once the user signs this pdf, they are redirected to a webpage that I have specified in my code. Appended to the end of this specified url, is ?documentKey=3r3t33hhjijij
If I am also watching my console, I see what I posted above and it's logged. I need this documentKey stored for the next part of my program.

Comment: Ok, I got it to store it, now I need to figure out how to use it. Bare with me, I may have another question in a bit. Thanks!